# JNDI Session Factory Error with Tomcat and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jndi, tomcat7, hibernate-tools

I am building a web application framework by making use of Spring MVC, Hibernate, JBoss Tools and JSFs. I have managed to generate domain classes and DAO classes by making use of JBoss Tools, however, when I try to construct the any DAO object(At the moment I am constructing the service but ultimately the service will be injected into the controller), I receive a JNDI error. I am using Tomcat 7 as the AS. I would appreciate a simple solution to this problem.

Controller Code:

```
AuthorHome ah = new AuthorHome();
Author a = ah.findById(1);
```

DAO/Service Code:

```
public class AuthorHome {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AuthorHome.class);

private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();

protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    try {
        return (SessionFactory) new InitialContext().lookup("SessionFactory");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI", e);
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI");
    }
}
}
```

Stack Trace:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name SessionFactory is not bound in this Context
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:803)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
>       at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>       at com.webapplication.service.AuthorHome.getSessionFactory(AuthorHome.java:31)
>       at com.webapplication.service.AuthorHome.(AuthorHome.java:26)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the Hibernate Session Factory inside of Spring.  See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-session-factory-setup.  Also note that direct use of Hibernate inside of Spring requires a transactional context.  A simple way to do so is to use the `@Transactional` annotation.  Details here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations.

Comment: Thank you for the references. I didn't solve the problem by making use of the suggested content, however, it did guide me in the right direction and I am sure it will be useful in the future. It was something silly really, the services couldn't find my hibernate.cfg.xml as the path it was referencing was incorrect.